# When and where did Remote Rendering Systems originate?

Tags: history

Remote rendering is system in which a server (on the cloud, usually) is performing rendering tasks (such as running a video game) and sends the rendering results to a remotely connected, thin device -- the client. This allows the user to run complex 3D rendering application without the need for specialized hardware and/or software.

I have read [A Survey of Interactive Remote Rendering Systems](https://dl.acm.org/purchase.cfm?id=2719921&CFID=759029341&CFTOKEN=43535360), which claims that such systems arose early when computers were not powerful enough to run computationally intensive graphical applications. I have [followed the source](https://www.sgi.com/pdfs/4429.pdf) and read that too, however, neither mention a date nor company or application in which this approach first appears.

Does anyone here know a bit more or have a better idea of when Remote Rendering systems arose?

Comment: You should be able to see the date when those papers were published.  Have you done a literature search to see if there are any earlier papers?  Check out the related work sections of those papers, check out other publications of those same authors, use Google Scholar to find related articles (I think you can narrow down by year), etc.